# Slim only accepts the block form of link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view-helpers, slim-lang

The following:

```
= link_to 'New', new_photo_path
```

raises:

```
undefined method `stringify_keys' for "/photos/new":String
```

However, this works:

```
= link_to new_photo_path do
  = 'New'
```

Why is that?

Full trace:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `stringify_keys' for "/photos/new":String:
  actionview (4.1.5) lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb:562:in `convert_options_to_data_attributes'
  actionview (4.1.5) lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb:179:in `link_to'
  app/views/layouts/application.html.slim:12:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_slim___3879750285739199800_69912892033540'
  actionview (4.1.5) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.1.5) lib/action_view/template.rb:339:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.1.5) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
  actionview (4.1.5) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:67:in `render_with_layout'
  actionview (4.1.5) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `render_template'
  actionview (4.1.5) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in `render'
  actionview (4.1.5) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
  actionview (4.1.5) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
  actionview (4.1.5) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:99:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
  actionview (4.1.5) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:82:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
  /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:294:in `realtime'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
  actionview (4.1.5) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:232:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:678:in `call'
  dragonfly (1.0.7) lib/dragonfly/middleware.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  better_errors (2.0.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (2.0.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (2.0.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.1.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  quiet_assets (1.0.3) lib/quiet_assets.rb:23:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
  dragonfly (1.0.7) lib/dragonfly/cookie_monster.rb:9:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.1.5) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.5) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  thin (1.6.2) lib/thin/connection.rb:86:in `block in pre_process'
  thin (1.6.2) lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `pre_process'
  thin (1.6.2) lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
  thin (1.6.2) lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
  eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
  thin (1.6.2) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
  thin (1.6.2) lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:16:in `run'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
  railties (4.1.5) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `start'
  railties (4.1.5) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
  railties (4.1.5) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
  railties (4.1.5) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
  railties (4.1.5) lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
  bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
  spring (1.1.3) lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `call'
  spring (1.1.3) lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
  spring (1.1.3) lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
  spring (1.1.3) bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
  spring (1.1.3) lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  bin/spring:16:in `<top (required)>'
  bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Beginning of `application.html.slim`:

```
html lang='en'
  head
    meta charset='UTF-8'
    title Some title
    = stylesheet_link_tag 'application'
    = csrf_meta_tags

  body
    #page-wrapper
      #page
        header
          = link_to new_photo_path, class: 'upload-button-icon main-nav-logo' do
            = ''
```

Comment: To understand your problem, please provide full trace

Comment: @MikDiet here you go.

Comment: And show please `app/views/layouts/application.html.slim` that raises this error.

Comment: @MikDiet here you go again.

Comment: Can you do `rake routes | grep photo` so we can see what your routes look like for the photo resources?

Comment: Has your issue been resolved?

Comment: Can you include the beginning snippet of your `application.html.slim` file, except showing what you use when you declare your `link_to` on one line instead of the block? Basically, to show the entire beginning snippet of what's actually throwing an error for you.